# Не работают запросы SQL в OpenOffice Base

Tags: sql, ubuntu, open-office

Начала знакомиться с SQL по книге Форта Б. "Освой самостоятельно SQL. 10 минут на урок". На сайте автора прилагаются таблицы для практики. Я скачала таблицу для OpenOffice (Ubuntu 10.04). Первые запросы выполнялись без проблем, результат совпадал с книжным, но когда дошла до

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE ... OR .. /
WHERE ... IN ...
```

результат перестал совпадать или вообще выводятся только названия столбцов. По этому поводу 2 вопроса:

1. Есть ли какие-то особенности в запросах OpenOffice?
2. Может лучше установить для практики какую-то программу? Если да, посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если синтаксической ошибки не возникает, значит нет. Если вы не можете контролировать правильность выполнения запроса по тем данным, которые есть в таблицах, то опубликуйте данные, условие задачи и запрос здесь.
2. Можно практиковаться онлайн [здесь](http://sql-ex.ru/).

Comment: 1. Это пока еще даже не задачи, а примеры. Т.е. все за меня написано, я должна ввести и получить аналогичный результат. Таблицы здесь - http://www.forta.com/books/0672325675/ 
допустим, запрос
SELECT prod_name, prod_price
FROM Products
WHERE vend_id = 'DLLO1' OR vend_id = 'BRSO1'
ORDER BY prod_name;
выводит только название столбцов. без WHERE все ок.

2. За ссылку большое спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте

     SELECT count(*) FROM Products WHERE vend_id = 'DLLO1' OR vend_id = 'BRSO1';
     SELECT count(*) FROM Products WHERE RTRIM(vend_id) = 'DLLO1' OR RTRIM(vend_id) = 'BRSO1';

Интересно, что будет в результате? (В первом случае д.б. 0)

Comment: попробовала. результат: Syntax Error in SQL expression :o)

Comment: Значит нам 0 (НОЛЬ), а не буква О.
Копируйте константы.

Comment: В смысле
WHERE vend_id = 'DLL01' OR vend_id = 'BRS01'

Comment: хм. странно. я в самом начале проверяла "О" или ноль, чтобы не ошибиться. остановилась на "О". все-таки "ноль". спасибо! заработало.
ошибка называется - невнимательность автора.